# How to set the button which was created using DOM to show only the details of the current row

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I created a table which shows the country details dynamically from the API. Now I'm trying to add a button at the end of the table which on clicked should show additional details (continents, latlng, official, timezones) in popup from the API related to that country but I'm getting all the country details when I click any of the button. How to fix that. I need to show only the country details that is present on the same row if the button on that row is clicked. I'll also share the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/manosurya91/1tk3dsyL/15/

```
HTML code:
<table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>S.NO</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Capital</th>
            <th>Currency</th>
            <th>Population</th>
            <th>Flag</th>
            <th>More details</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="popup" id="popup-1">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="popup-header">
          <div class="title">Country details</div>
          <button onclick="togglePopup()" class="close-button">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="popup-body"></div>
      </div>
JS code:
const tableBody = document.querySelector("table tbody");
const searchInput = document.querySelector("#search-country-captial");
const popup = document.querySelector(".popup");
const popupBody = document.querySelector(".popup-body");

let response, data;
const countryList = async function (url) {
  response = await fetch(url);
  data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
  tableBody.innerHTML = data
    .map((country, i) => {
      return `<tr>
        <td>${i + 1}</td><td>${country.name.common}</td>
        <td>${country.capital[0] || "-"}</td>
      <td>${
        Object.entries(country.currencies)[0]
          ? Object.entries(country.currencies)[0][1].symbol
          : "-"
      }</td>
      <td>${country.population}</td>
      <td><img src="${country.flags.svg}"/></td>
      **<td><button class="details" onclick="togglePopup()">More details</button></td>**
      </tr>
      `;
    })
    .join("");
};

**function togglePopup() {
  popupBody.innerHTML = data.map((country, i) => {
    return `<p>Country: ${country.name.common}</p>
        <p>Continent: ${country.continents}</p>
        <p>Latitue: ${country.latlng[0]}, Longiture: ${country.latlng[1]}</p>
        <p>Official: ${country.name.official}</p>
        <p>TimeZone: ${country.timezones}</p>`;
  }).join("")
  popup.classList.toggle("active");
}**
countryList(
  "https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all?fields=name,capital,currencies,flags,population,continents,latlng,official,timezones"
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were mapping through an array of all countries and were setting inner html to all countries from an array.

You need to get data from the table for a specific country and then find this country in an array of all countries you're fetching.

```js
if (e.target.className !== "details") {
      popup.classList.toggle("active");
      return;
}

const countryName =
    e.target.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].textContent;

const [country] =  data.filter(country => country.name.common === 'Kuwait')
      
      popupBody.innerHTML = `<p>Country: ${country.name.common}</p>
                <p>Continent: ${country.continents}</p>
                <p>Latitue: ${country.latlng[0]}, Longiture: ${country.latlng[1]}</p>
                <p>Official: ${country.name.official}</p>
                <p>TimeZone: ${country.timezones}</p>`;
              
      popup.classList.t

oggle("active");
```

This code works you only need to replace 'Kuwait' with the common country name you get from your DOM.

Comment: Is it possible to do that dynamically for all the countries? If a button on a row is clicked it should display the details of the current row. In this scenario when I click any button it's showing the details of Kuwait country, it should be the country located on that row.

Comment: @mjj Yes that's what I am saying, you should be able to get that from the event and then replace 'Kuwait' with this value.

Comment: I'm getting an error as cannot read properties of undefined (reading "target"). Can you please check on what's the mistake on this code https://jsfiddle.net/manosurya91/1tk3dsyL/18/

Comment: @mjj add event property where you call the function like that <button onclick="togglePopup(event)" class="close-button"> and same in your javascript where you are setting innerHtml

Comment: I appreciate your assistance. It works now :)

Answer (score 0):

create full table and fetch the data into your table from API, like you were doing before. After this add button
 `<button id="btn" class="btn" onclick="toggleHide()"></button>`
and then give an class to the table element which element you want to display on click on button for example I give **toggle** class to table element which I want to show on click

```
function toggleHide() {
var hide = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle');
hide.style.display = 'none'; 
if (hide.style.display == 'none') {
    hide.style.display == 'block';
} else {
    hide.style.display == 'none';
}
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your response. My task is to show the details of continents, latlng, official, timezones in a pop up not as a table. I already created a popup. Any idea on how to show these in pop up when the button is clicked. For example, if the button on Kuwait row is clicked it should display the continents, latlng, official, timezones of Kuwait.